# simple question of pushViewController

Tags: iphone

messagecontroller  is  nothing but object of initialize  nib file.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:messageController animated:YES];
```

this statement executes in normal condition

this statement also works on state maintainace testing ,
this line executes properly but not open new view ,why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling this method call does not push a new view?
If this is the question you should ask yourself some questions:

1. Is `self` having an
   `UINavigationController`? Make sure
   `self` is a view controller
   **inside** a navigation controller.
2. Is `messageController` initialized
   correctly? Like this for example (if
   messageController is an ivar):

   ```
   messageController = [[MyViewControllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewControllerClassNibName" bundle:nil];
   ```

Comment: ok
1>my 5 th view is acontroller
  it has 1 UIButton
  when i click on UIButton bcontroller opens

 it work perfectly

second type of operation

 2 >
now i  go to 5 th controller that is acontroller
now  i press home button
3>now when i again click on application
  i directly go to acontroller as per state maintainance rule.
  now when i click UIButton bcontroller view not opens why

the code for pushing view on click of UIButton
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bcontroller animated:YES];

Comment: Don't know. So you're restoring the navigation controller stack when the user opens the app again and pushing `bcontroller` doesn't work anymore!? Sounds like you did it right to me. The only thing I can add is that you check exactly what differences there are between the "normal" behaviour and the one you get when you "load" the previous state.

Comment: There is no difference ,in 1st operation tlhat pushviewcontroller line executes and new view opens  but in second case pushviewcontroller line executes but new view not opens.plzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz help me

Comment: Edit your question and include the code that you use to "save the state" of your navigation controller stack/hierarchy. This will maybe help to answer your question.